# How can I disable Mail.app when I click on an email address on mac?

Tags: macos, email, apple-mail

By default, clicking on an email address from another mac app (such as Slack) launches the Mail.app application in a compose view to that email address.

I would like to disable this - I never use the Mail.app and most times I encounter an email address I'd like to copy/paste it somewhere else, not compose an email to that person.

Is there a way to disable that behavior?

Comment: Please don't cross-post from one SE site to another. It's considered bad form. Pick one & stick with it. Ref: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/235598/how-can-i-disable-mail-app-when-i-click-on-an-email-address

Comment: My apologies. It seems like this one is being voted down, so I *would* remove it, but it also contains the correct answer whereas the other post does not.

Comment: Yeah, this is a better answer. I'd leave both & see what happens, in this particular case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use RubiCode's RCDefaultApp (http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) to configure the default handlers for different "protocols" like `http:`, `mailto:`, etc.

Not 100% positive that you can disable the protocol handler altogether, but you can definitely redirect it to something other than Mail.app.

Answer (score 0):

download the setdefaultmailapp. just tested in Big Sur.

this works and its simple and direct from MS!

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/outlook-for-mac/useful-tools#setdefaultmailapp.

Comment: Link is now obsolete (404).